# jQuery: How to get parameters of a url?

Tags: jquery, parameters, get, href, param

New to jQuery and I'm having trouble getting the parameters of a url that my server generates. I have a url like this:

```
<span class="popuptest"><a href="www.example.com/test?param1=1&param2=2">find param</a></span>
```

my jquery function looks like so:

```
$(function() {
  $('.popuptest a').live('click', function(event) {
  $.extend({
    getUrlVars: function(){
      var vars = [], hash;
      var hashes = this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
      for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
      {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
      }
      return vars;
    },
    getUrlVar: function(name){
      return $.getUrlVars()[name];
    }
  });
  var second = getUrlVars()["param2"];
  alert(second);
  return false;
  });
});
```

clicking on the link should show me "2", however I get nothing... any help for a jQuery noob? thanks in advance!

I found this on a blog: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @FelixKling True, but I think this is a better question than the original, which has no example URL and no code.  How it got so many upvotes is a mystery.

Comment: @Bill: You are right... I was just thinking because one answer here just references the other question and another one basically copied the code from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

You don't need jQuery for that purpose you can use the pure JavaScript:

```
function getParameterByName( name,href )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and you can call the function in this way..`getParameterByName(param1,href of your link)`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TvMCP/)

Comment: Of course you don't need jQuery. How do you suppose jQuery works? It uses JavaScript. The point of jQuery is convenience.

Answer (score 13):

small improvement, parse the url only once, return array or params:

```
function getURLParameters(url){

    var result = {};
    var hashIndex = url.indexOf("#");
    if (hashIndex > 0)
       url = url.substr(0, hashIndex);        
    var searchIndex = url.indexOf("?");
    if (searchIndex == -1 ) return result;
    var sPageURL = url.substring(searchIndex +1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {       
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');      
        result[sParameterName[0]] = sParameterName[1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shakhal/gXM3u/

Answer (score 7):

it's so easy, all you have to do is put the variable name that you want it from the URL into this function then it will return you the value of URL variable

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
 return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Jquery have in build functions for get param form URL.

```
var url="http://example.com/?id=76dc915c-b1c2-47f6-ae63-a3ea6ce78f2a";

let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)

searchParams.has('id') // true

let paramId = searchParams.get('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery could be

```
$(function() {  
 $('.popuptest a').live('click', function(event) {
 $.extend({     getUrlVars: function(){
  var vars = [], hash;
  var hashes = $('.popuptest a').attr("href").slice($('.popuptest     a').attr("href").indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
  {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
},
getUrlVar: function(name){
  return $.getUrlVars()[name];
}
  });
  var second = $.getUrlVars()["param2"];
  alert(second);
  return false;
  });
});
```

things to note:

1. $.getUrlVars in line - var second = $.getUrlVars()["param2"];
2. this.href is replaced to $('.popuptest a').attr("href")

Answer (score 1):

from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/)

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

// example.com?param1=name&param2=&id=6
$.urlParam('param1'); // name
$.urlParam('id');        // 6
$.urlParam('param2');   // null
```

Answer (score 1):

So simple you can use any url and get value in Javascript.And this is Complete set of codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var tech = getQueryVariable('filename');
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
alert(tech);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Get parameters of a url</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using code below for some time, but recently discoverd a problem with an base64_encode string in the URL, having == at the end, like: /index.php?a=1&b=2&c=Mw==&d=4.

Using getUrlVar("c") gives me 'Mw' as result, but this should be 'Mw==', so added an extra line:

```
 $.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
   var vars = [], hash;
   var hashes = $('.popuptest a').attr("href").slice($('.popuptest a').attr("href").indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
   for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
   {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    if (hash.length > 2) hash[1] = hash.slice(1).join('=');
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
   }
   return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
   return $.getUrlVars()[name];
 }
});
```