# javascript - simple but viral logical issue

Tags: javascript

I have a url:

```
domain.com/?page=2&show=10&sortterm=km
```

If I sort for the second time, url is becoming

```
domain.com/?page=2&show=10&sortterm=km&sortterm=km
```

What i want to do is:

```
1. see if url has "?" in it
2. if yes, 
  2.1. see if "sortterm" exists in url
  2.2. if yes, replace that "&sortterm=x" with new "&sortterm=y"
  2.3. if not, add "&sortterm=y"
3. if not
  3.1 add "?sortterm=y"
```

this is my code:

```
var url = String(window.location);
if(url.indexOf("?") !== -1){
  if(url.indexOf('sortterm') !== -1){
    var newurl = url +'&sortterm='+sortterm; 
   //^ but i need to replace here, and the value of sortterm can be different. 
  }
...
...
```

I am a bit stuck, pleas help!

Comment: You could do `url.replace(/&sortterm=.*/,'&sortterm=' + sortterm)` or something like that

Comment: @putvande, wooo, is it working code what you wrote here? i didnot know about this, this is cool.. can i take it?

Comment: You have to check that sortterm is not the first parameter after the query though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073859/jquery-how-to-get-parameters-of-a-url may help you to a more complex answer

Comment: @vogomatix, If ``?``-test not true, then sortterm will be the first parameter, right?

Comment: Maybe this than: `url.replace(/&sortterm=[a-z0-9]+/i,'&sortterm=' + sortterm)`?

Comment: url.replace(/([&?])sortterm=(\w+)/,'\1sortterm='+sorterm) maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
url = url.replace(/([&?]sortterm=)[^&]*/, "$1" + sortterm)
```