# Using jQuery ajax method to pass GET parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use the jQuery ajax method to process a form. In the php script that I call (myScript.php) I'd like to use the GET value that is set by submitting the form within the php script but it is not passing through properly.

```
<script>
 $('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax ( {
            url: "myScript.php",
            success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
            }
        } );
    });
</script>
```

My form has one field (username):

```
<form id='myForm' action="" method="get">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" />
    <button id='submitButton' name="">Search</button>
<form>
```

And finally, my php script will just return back the get value.

```
<?php 
$returnString = array();
$returnString['username'] = $_GET['username'];
echo json_encode($returnString);
?>
```

The console returns:
{"username":null} regardless of what value you type in the input box.

Comment: You're not passing any data *into* your AJAX request.

Comment: You have to send the data the user has submitted using the **data** attribute of the **.ajax()** method. Search stackoverflow, there are tons of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form data:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

     $.ajax ( {
        url: "myScript.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
    } );
});
```

Anything in the [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) property will get appended to the end of the URL according to spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` feature of your ajax string:

```
type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". 
Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can 
also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Or, you can just make the window redirect with the variable in the URL as a string:
[how do I pass Jquery value to a different page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486437/how-do-i-pass-jquery-value-to-a-different-page/22486533#22486533)